# finding a route to form mode and add it local tasks

Tags: forms, 8, routes

I have a content type named "film" and a form mode named "film_artistic"

in **my_module.routing.yml**, I have added this entry:

```
my_module.film.artistic:
  path: 'node/{node}/artistic/edit'
  defauts:
    _entity_form: node.film_artistic
    _title: 'Edit artistic info'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

But when I try to reach, let say "**/node/6/artistic/edit**" I got a "Page not found" result

I don't know what I am missing...

My ultimate goal is to have several **form mode** for my film content type (ex: Artistic, Technical,...) and for each of them, I would like to create a "Local Task" sharing the same base_route: "**entity.node.edit_form**".
For my first local task, I have to add the following in **my_module.links.task.yml**:

```
film.artist:
  route_name: my_module.film.artistic
  title: Edit artistic info 
  base_route: entity.node.edit_form
  weight: 20
```

But of course I can't test it as my main route is not working (node/{node}/artistic/edit)

Answer (score 0):

I could find a solution with an handy module: https://www.drupal.org/project/form_mode_control

After installation, you can reach any form by using :

```
 www.your-site.com/node/add/my_content_type?display=machine_name_of_your_form
```

or

```
www.your-site.com/node/{node}/edit?display=machine_name_of_your_form
```

More then this, this module allow you to set permission to access each form mode.

I am still looking for how to add those forms as local task... but the main thing is done

My objective is: if I go to node/add, or node/{node}/edit, I would like to have the default form displayed but also, all the form mode accessible as Tabs (local task)